# Как поменять стандартные боковые кнопки на другие в swiper слайдере?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    loop: true,
  
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
  
    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.slider-box {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 600px;
}

.swiper-container {
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Aclonica&family=Montserrat&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&family=Raleway:wght@600;700&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300&family=ZCOOL+XiaoWei&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>CAFENA</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="slider-box">
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

В html вставить картинки другого стиля а, в CSS в свойствах
.swiper-button-next::after,
.swiper-button-prev::after
прописать content. И все работает.